# Extracting differences between two tables - MS Access SQL Query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join, union

What I need to do is display all differences between the two tables;
All the records that exist in TABLE1 but not TABLE2, the records that exist in TABLE2 but not TABLE1, and the records that don't have a matching Amount in the other table.

I have two tables:

```
(TABLE 1)
CO_CODE   ACCOUNT_ID   CONTRACT    STATUS          AMT
A         7              101       ACTIVE          5,497.00
A         7              101       ACTIVE          5,482.00
A         15             106       INACTIVE        0.00
A         23             102       ACTIVE          4,562.00
A         31             102       ACTIVE          22.00
A         49             103       ACTIVE          1,900.00
A         49             103       ACTIVE          135.00

(TABLE 2)
Company      Account_Number    Amount      Agreement
A            7                 5,497.00    S000101
A            23                8,457.00    S000102
A            49                135.00      S000103          
A            56                2,465.00    S000104              
A            7                 5,482.00    S000101
```

The two tables share the fields with the Company ID, Account Number, Amount, and Agreement/Contract# where the Agreement in TABLE2 is type Text but is numerical in TABLE1.

So far, I've come up with:

```
SELECT TABLE1.CO_CODE AS Company, TABLE1.ACCOUNT_ID AS [Account Number], TABLE1.CONTRACT As [Contract Number], TABLE1.STATUS AS Status, TABLE1.AMT, TABLE2.Amount
FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ACCOUNT_ID = TABLE2.Account_Number
WHERE ((Exists (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1.CO_CODE = TABLE2.Company AND TABLE1.ACCOUNT_ID = TABLE2.Account_number AND TABLE1.CONTRACT = Clng(MID(TABLE2.Agreement,5)) AND TABLE1.AMT = TABLE2.Amount))=False) OR ((Exists (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.CO_CODE = TABLE2.Company AND TABLE1.ACCOUNT_ID = TABLE2.Account_number AND TABLE1.CONTRACT = Clng(MID(TABLE2.Agreement,5)) AND TABLE1.AMT = TABLE2.Amount))=False)

UNION ALL 

SELECT TABLE2.Company, TABLE2.Account_Number, CLng(MID(TABLE2.Agreement, 5)), TABLE1.ACC_STATUS, TABLE1.AMT, TABLE2.Amount
FROM TABLE2 LEFT JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE1.ACCOUNT_ID = TABLE2.Account_Number 
WHERE TABLE1.ACCOUNT_ID NOT IN (SELECT Account_Number FROM TABLE2) OR TABLE2.Account_Number NOT IN (SELECT ACCOUNT_ID FROM TABLE1);
```

This gives me the result:

```
Company  Account    Contract    Status       AMT           Amount
A         15         106        INACTIVE     0.00   
A         23         102        ACTIVE       4,562.00      8,457.00
A         31         102        ACTIVE       22.00    
A         49         103        ACTIVE       1,900.00      135.00
A         56         104                                   2,465.00
```

Account 49 with an amount of 135.00 should not show the amount of 135.00, as it occurs in both tables, however the amt of 1900.00 is correct (it only appears in TABLE1).

**Could someone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?**

I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge in MS Access SQL and this website in general. I've been struggling the past week trying to figure out how to obtain the desired results and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not confident enough in SQL to be able to tell you how to fix this, but I think I have an idea of why it is happening. In the first part of your query, before the `UNION ALL`, your `WHERE` clause is telling it to return columns from both tables where the Amount is not the same between both tables. Since Account 49 has the amount 1900 in one table but not the other, the `WHERE` clause will be true and it will select the columns you specified, which includes the Amounts from both tables. That is why it is showing 135 even though it is in both tables.

Comment: @jaredk that seems like a reasonable cause to the problem! Thank you for your insight. Now to try and fix this..

Comment: Is it a requirement that you show the Amount fields separately, or can they be combined into one column?

Comment: @jaredk The reason they are shown separately is so that it is apparent which table the discrepency orginates from. For example, account 56 only exists in TABLE2, clear from the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am by no means an expert with SQL, so my solution may be inefficient or even plain wrong, but it was working on my own testing environment.

Try the following:

```
SELECT T1.CO_CODE AS Company, T1.ACCOUNT_ID AS [Account Number], T1.STATUS AS Status,  T1.CONTRACT As [Contract Number], T1.AMT AS [Table 1], "" AS [Table 2]    
FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 T2 
WHERE T1.CO_CODE = T2.Company 
AND T1.Account_ID = T2.Account_Number
AND T1.CONTRACT = CLng(MID(TABLE2.Agreement, 5))
AND T1.AMT = T2.Amount
)

UNION ALL

SELECT T2.Company, T2.Account_Number AS [Account Number], "" AS Status, CLng(MID(TABLE2.Agreement, 5)) AS [Contract Number],  "" AS [Table 1], T2.Amount AS [Table 2]    
FROM TABLE2 T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 
WHERE T1.CO_CODE = T2.Company 
AND T1.Account_ID = T2.Account_Number
AND T1.CONTRACT = CLng(MID(TABLE2.Agreement, 5))    
AND T1.AMT = T2.Amount
)
```

Which results in the following:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|Company|Account Number| Status |Contract Number|Table 1|Table 2|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   A   |      15      |INACTIVE|      106      | 0     |       |
|   A   |      23      | ACTIVE |      102      | 4562  |       |
|   A   |      31      | ACTIVE |      102      | 22    |       |
|   A   |      49      | ACTIVE |      103      | 1900  |       |
|   A   |      23      |        |      102      |       | 8457  |
|   A   |      56      |        |      104      |       | 2465  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I didn't know what types each of your columns were, so the query may need to be modified a bit to match your data. You may also want to rename the columns to something else, I was just throwing in data.

Notice that records where there are two different amounts in each table show up twice (i.e. Account #23 from your example). I don't know if this is acceptable behaviour or not for you, but it is what I came up with.

I hope this helps, or at least gives you something else to try.